# Heroku PHP Refuses more than one query

Tags: php, mysql, heroku

I've setup my `index.PHP` file in Heroku to query the database four (4) distinct times and two (2) update queries during the `authenticateUser` action. However, from the XML result, it appears that only the first query is completed and then the remainder are ignored thus creating a truncated XML result and without even the closing `</data>` tag.

I believe Heroku is able handle this action as it is not too complex and worked with XAMPP on my local computer and Google Compute Engine without any modifications required.

Why would Heroku only allow the completion of the first query, then terminate the remainder of the action?

How can I make this work?

**index.PHP file (authenticateUser action):**

```
case "authenticateUser":
// and return friends and messages

    if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)) 
    {                   

        // providerId and requestId is Id of  a friend pair,
        // providerId is the Id of making first friend request
        // requestId is the Id of the friend approved the friend request made by providerId

        // fetching friends, 
        // left join expression is a bit different, 
        //      it is required to fetch the friend, not the users itself

        $sqlFriends = "select u.Id, u.username, (NOW()-u.authenticationTime) as authenticateTimeDifference, u.IP, 
                                    f.providerId, f.requestId, f.status, u.port 
                        from friends f
                        left join users u on 
                                    u.Id = if ( f.providerId = ".$userId.", f.requestId, f.providerId ) 
                        where (f.providerId = ".$userId." and f.status=".USER_APPROVED.")  or 
                                     f.requestId = ".$userId." ";

        //$sqlmessage = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `touid` = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";

        $sqlIndMessage = "SELECT m.id, m.fromuid, m.touid, m.sentdt, m.read, m.readdt, m.messagetext, u.username, m.shared_campaign_id, m.shared_campaign_location_id from messages m \n"
. "left join users u on u.Id = m.fromuid WHERE `touid` = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";

        // Queries for selecting groups and group chats
        // Selecting list of groups
        $sqlGroups = "SELECT groupId, groupName 
                      FROM users_groups 
                      WHERE usersId = ".$userId." ";

        // Get group messages related to that users group, note: even if didn't send any messages as all
        // will need all messages related to that group and the user name of the user sending them
        // finally: even if not a friend of a group memeber, can still get the messages they send

        /*
        $sqlGroupMessages = "SELECT gm.id, usr.username as 'fromUser', gm.fromUId, gm.toGroupId, gm.sentdt, gm.read, gm.readdt, gm.messageText 
                             FROM group_messages gm 
                             left join users usr on gm.fromUId = usr.Id
                             WHERE gm.toGroupId IN (SELECT groupId 
                                                    FROM users_groups
                                                    WHERE usersId = ".$userId.") AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30";
        */

        // Because if not in the group/no messages sent to them , should be empty
        $sqlGroupMessages = "SELECT id, myId, fromUser, fromUId, toGroupName, toGroupId,  sentdt,  `read`,  readdt,  messageText, shared_campaign_id, shared_campaign_location_id 
                 FROM group_messages 
                 WHERE myId = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30";

        // Test setting the textsize to a large number:
        $txtSize = "SET TEXTSIZE 3000";
        exec($txtSize);

        if ($result = $db->query($sqlFriends))          
        {
            $out .= "<data>"; 
            $out .= "<user userKey='".$userId."' />";
            while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
            {
                $status = "offline";
                if (((int)$row->status) == USER_UNAPPROVED)
                {
                    $status = "unApproved";
                }
                else if (((int)$row->authenticateTimeDifference) < TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS)
                {
                    $status = "online";

                }
                $out .= "<friend  username = '".$row->username."'  status='".$status."' IP='".$row->IP."' userKey = '".$row->Id."'  port='".$row->port."'/>";

                                        // to increase security, we need to change userKey periodically and pay more attention
                                        // receiving message and sending message 

            }   // Getting the individual messages
                if ($resultmessage = $db->query($sqlIndMessage))            
                {
                    while ($rowmessage = $resultmessage->fetch_object())
                    {
                    $out .= "<message  from='".$rowmessage->username."'  sendt='".$rowmessage->sentdt."' text='".$rowmessage->messagetext."' shared_campaign_id='".$rowmessage->shared_campaign_id."' shared_campaign_location_id='".$rowmessage->shared_campaign_location_id."' />";
                    $sqlendmsg = "UPDATE `messages` SET `read` = 1, `readdt` = '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."' WHERE `messages`.`id` = ".$rowmessage->id.";";
                    $db->query($sqlendmsg);
                    }
                }

                // Get the groups
                if ($resultGroup = $db->query($sqlGroups)) 
                {
                    while ($rowGroup = $resultGroup->fetch_object())
                    {
                        $out .= "<groups groupName = '".$rowGroup->groupName."' groupId = '".$rowGroup->groupId."' />";
                    }

                    // Get Group messages
                    if ($resultGroupMessage = $db->query($sqlGroupMessages))
                    { 
                        while ($rowGroupMessage = $resultGroupMessage->fetch_object())
                        {
                            $out .= "<group_message fromUser='".$rowGroupMessage->fromUser."' fromUId='".$rowGroupMessage->fromUId."' toGroupName = '".$rowGroupMessage->toGroupName."' toGroupId = '".$rowGroupMessage->toGroupId."'
                                    sentdt = '".$rowGroupMessage->sentdt."' messageText='".$rowGroupMessage->messageText."' shared_campaign_id='".$rowGroupMessage->shared_campaign_id."' shared_campaign_location_id='".$rowGroupMessage->shared_campaign_location_id."' />";
                            $sqlGroupEndMsg = "UPDATE `group_messages` SET `read` = 1, `readdt` = NOW() WHERE `group_messages`.`id` = ".$rowGroupMessage->id.";";
                            $db->query($sqlGroupEndMsg);
                        }
                    }


                    error_log($out, 0);
                    $out .= "</data>";


                }  

        }
        else
        {
            error_log($out, 0);
            $out = FAILED;
        }           
    }
    else
    {
            // exit application if not authenticated user
            error_log($out, 0);
            $out = FAILED;
    }

break;
```

**UPDATE:** The error log simply notes `SET: not found` without reporting a line:

[image]

Comment: You have a fatal error somewhere, that's why the XML is truncated. PHP crashes. Look at `heroku logs` to see what's happening. If there is nothing in there, you have either set `error_reporting` to something like 0, or your `$db` abstraction layer does `@mysql_query()`, suppressing errors, so all you get is a crash with no error output. You really need to update your code to follow some best practices that are not from the 90s.

Comment: You concatenate SQL queries by hand without escaping values, which will lead to security vulnerabilities through SQL injection. You're also building XML by hand instead of using DOM or XMLWriter, which will lead to the same issues (and potentially invalid XML). And I have no idea what the `exec()` call is even supposed to do with that `SET TEXTSIZE 3000` command... you're running a local shell command, not an SQL query, with that... it's never going to do anything...

Comment: Thank you, the error that appears simply that `SET: not found` without referencing a line, I updated my question with the error output

Comment: First, that `SET ...` command has nothing to do with it. You are running that through `exec` (really, really bad idea, and the doesn't look like it knows what that's even supposed to do), but it's only failing, not crashing. You should still at least try to understand what it is for (it's for MSSQL clients on Windows environments, so completely useless in your case) and try to remove it.

Comment: Second, looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044341/heroku-php-truncates-xml-messages, it becomes obvious that the `if ($resultmessage = $db->query($sqlIndMessage))` and `if ($resultGroup = $db->query($sqlGroups))` do not return a valid result and thus those branches of your code never execute. Because the `</data>` part is wrongly output in the second of the branches I mentioned above, the data appears truncated, when in fact, everything runs correctly.

Comment: Your queries are not returning a result. Why don't you output the queries before you run them for debug purposes to check them, and run them against your database? Or somehow enable error reporting in your code for queries? You still haven't even responded to the remark about `error_reporting` I made earlier.

Comment: This is not a question for Stack Overflow. There is nothing wrong with Heroku, and Heroku is not "refusing" to run more than one query. Something in your code is not working like you expect, and you need help with (or learn) debugging it, but Stack Overflow is not the right forum for that.

Comment: @dzuelke how is it obvious they do not return a valid result? The group's query is very straightforward and simply returns the group's

Comment: @dzuelke I found the problem, it had nothing to do with the index.PHP file. Turns out that the export and import into MySQL workbench prevented any table with a trigger from being imported...but never reported the error. So when it notes `SET: not found`, it literally meant there was no table to pull from and cause FATAL error in PHP. Thank you for the device,

Comment: It is obvious, @Sauron, because I read your code, and I understood it, and the explanation for the other parts of the XML not getting output is because the `if ($resultmessage = $db->query($sqlIndMessage))` and `if ($resultGroup = $db->query($sqlGroups))` return `false`.

Comment: The `SET: not found` does not come from the database or that there are no tables to pull from. It comes from your code. The error log output you posted even says "sh: 1: SET: not found", meaning that the shell cannot run the command you gave it, and you do that here in the code you posted: `$txtSize = "SET TEXTSIZE 3000"; exec($txtSize);`. That call is, like I am now explaining to you for the third time, not doing anything, but you don't seem to even understand what it is for or why it is there, not to mention what `exec()` even does (execute an external shell command).